# Wireshark display filter to hide Protocol = 802.11?

Tags: wireshark

[Note: reposted here from SO...]

I've set Wireshark's capture filter set to capture only packets from the MAC address of interest, but the result is dominated by zillions of packets whose Protocol is "802.11".  I want to view all of the packets that are NOT 802.11, e.g. ARP, DCHP, DNS, TCP, etc.

For example, in the following, I'd like to hide all of the 802.11 packets and show the DHCP packets (and any others that are NOT 802.11):

[image]

I tried "wlan.fc.type != 0", but clearly that's not correct.  What's the magic keyword for such a filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter out 802.11, the filter is

```
!wlan
```

From https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/w/wlan.html

Comment: Thank you!  I stared at that specific page for a while and it still wasn't clear that you could use a "naked" protocol name in a filter.  But just one problem: that filters my DHCP packets as well.

Comment: You could try `!wlan || dhcp`